# Different redirect based on referral

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I wanna know if its possible to redirect someone based on referal (url which he came from) i.e.:

1. If user A clicks link on facebook.com he will be redirected to a xxx.com/fb
2. If user A (the same user) clicks link on any other site than facebook he will be redirected to xxx.com/other

I wonder if it's possible to do.

I found one code that would help but i don't know how to modify it to make that if someone will came from any site besides Facebook.com they will be redirected to a xxx.com/other

Code i found:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http ://foo\ .com [NC]
RewriteRule pic\.jpg http ://mywebsite .com/pic.jpg [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http ://foo2\ .com [NC]
RewriteRule pic\.jpg http ://website .com/pic2.jpg [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond is the condition of the rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://foo\ .com [NC]
```

Means redirect if the HTTP REFERER starts with `http://foo.com` not sensitive to case ([NC])

So if you want to redirect from facebook, you would change foo by facebook...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://facebook\.com [NC]
```

The `\` is there to escape the `.` since it is a regular expression... Since facebook is https... You should consider that too:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://facebook\.com [NC,or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://facebook\.com [NC]
```

As for the rewrite rule, we'd need more information... We can reroute anything to a simple landing page, or use the path to link to a more accurate page. This will depend on you. For the landing page:

```
RewriteRule $1 http ://xxx.com/fb [R,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule $1 http ://xxx.com/fb [R,L]

That rule will do that if referer is from outside fb will redirect user to a xxx.com/fb ?

Comment: no, you put that after the rewriteCond... to redirect to facebook.